# aws elastic beanstalk pulling from existing environment

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, command-line, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an existing environment already in amazon. This is my first time to use the CLI tools. How can I connect my local repository to the already existing environment in AWS?

I tried following the instructions given in this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/GettingStarted.GetSetup-devtools.html) but it only shows me how to "deploy" a new application.

Answer (score 1):

It is an easy process.

1. Install eb and git.
2. eb init, if you already has an environment, just use that one.
3. eb create
4. git add your application
5. eb deploy

You can also reference here.[Pushing to an existing AWS Elastic Beanstalk application from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450454/pushing-to-an-existing-aws-elastic-beanstalk-application-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to use a CLI to manage an existing Elastic Beanstalk application. You can also look at [AWS CLI](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). You can refer [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/index.html) guide for using aws cli with Elastic Beanstalk.

Does that meet your requirements or is it necessary to use git for managing your existing environment?