# git aws.push uploaded new php application to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, git, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a similar question to [Pushing to an existing AWS Elastic Beanstalk application from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450454/pushing-to-an-existing-aws-elastic-beanstalk-application-from-the-command-line) and [Git pushes entire project even if few files are changed. AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21052774/git-pushes-entire-project-even-if-few-files-are-changed-aws) but did not see the answer I am looking for.

There have been comments about the confusing changes to Amazon's documentation because different versions of the documentation state they are the latest when some functions have actually been replaced and I think a new question is warranted now.

I used the [Deploying a Symfony2 Application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_symfony2.html) guide to setup my dev app and it works great.  After I make several changes and want to update the aws app, I use git aws.push which creates a new version of my app and restarts the server.

I do not have my configuration files finalized (this is just a dev app) and need to manually run several commands on the remote server before my app can be viewed.  For very minor temporary changes, I connected to the remote server via ssh and edited the php files directly which works fine.  This way the server does not need to be restarted because everyimt I use git aws.push the server restarts.  I would like to have a method  to update those files using git without restarting the entire server/app.

**Main question - Is there anyway I can push only the files that were changed in the recent commit and not have the server restart?**

Side question for new aws commands - Should I use the eb commands [Getting Started with EB CLI 3.x](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-getting-started.html) and use eb deploy instead of the git command?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, currently there is no scenario where Elastic Beanstalk pulls changes without reinitiating and restarting server.

> You can try to write your own workaround for that purpose, but you
>   will need to mention files that need to be updated manually and be
>   sure that files will be delivered to each EB instance. If you are
>   pushing from windows don't forget to convert line ending dos2unix.

2. **eb deploy** is a canonical command for **aws.push**
3. If you experience "full upload" issue instead of sending "only changes", please read my fresh answer here:
   [Elastic Beanstalk "git aws.push" only commited difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941775/elastic-beanstalk-git-aws-push-only-commited-difference/31361109#31361109)